# Feign and parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-cloud-feign

Normally a rest with pagination has methods with Criteria and Pagination
I need to call these method using Feign approach, but I have the error:

```
Method has too many Body parameters
```

My method call is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/server/myRequest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseEntity<String> getMyRequestByCriteriaClient(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authHeader, CriteriaCustom criteria, Pageable pageable);
```

(The CriteriaCustom is a simple pojo with getter and setter)

On the rest side I have:

```
    @GetMapping("/myRequest")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getMyRequestByCriteriaServer(CriteriaCustom criteria, Pageable pageable) {...}
```

How can I write the Client side call?
I try to pass criteria and pageable in a Map<String,Object> and @RequestParam but they not arrive on server side.

I can't believe it's impossible use Feign to call and pass criteria and pagination to the server. It's a simple GET!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're passing `CriteriaCustom` and `Pageable` as a body in GET request, which the server would happily ignore. And in your case, there are two bodies, hence the error - `Method has too many Body parameters`

So either you can pass them as Map<String, Object> `RequestParams`, or you could write your own encoder which could do that for all of your feigns.
You can find the code [here](https://source.coveo.com/2016/07/21/feign-request-object/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see a solution in the link you posted. For example: what is BaseRequest??? I tried Map<String, Object> and even pass a String with all the criteria (param1=alfa&param2=beta...), but they pass encoded (param1=alfa became param1%3alfa) and they are not viewed correctly by server.

Comment: It was just an example to get you started. So basically, would you need reflection to get all the key-value pairs from any object you pass from feign client and create them as request params (Map<String, Object>).  
The BaseRequest constitutes an example that you may or may not need.